# Latex - how to add caption in \begin{center}

Tags: graphics

I'm using this code for pictures, because `\begin{figure}` puts it in a bad place for me. How can I add a caption to this picture?

```latex
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=13.7cm, height=8.2cm]{pictures/c25k.png}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Load the `caption` package (if you're not using a KOMA-Script class) and use `\captionof{figure}{...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem you can use something like this:

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=13.7cm, height=8.2cm]{pictures/c25k.png}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\caption{Here the caption.}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
```

This may works for what you are asking. But remind that if you want a figure in a specific place you can use the following command:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
```

In the case, when compiling, the figure move in a different place/position this mean in the document there was not enough space for place the figure (this probably will happen also with the solution I proposed to you).

Comment: This solution doesn't seem suitable in general...

Comment: Why nesting `center` and `figure` environments? Also, why `\includegraphics` outside `figure` environment?

Comment: @MattAllegro, Werner, yes you both are right. This solution is not suitable in general. But the question asked a particular solution for a particular case.

Answer (score 8):

To force a figure to the current position, add

```
\usepackage{float}
```

to your preamble and use

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[<options>]{<image>}
  \caption{<caption>}
\end{figure}
```

If this is your choice, please consider also reading [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764)

---

Another option would be to use the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) which provides `\captionof{<float type>}` (the tiny [`capt-of` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) provides a similar interface):

```
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[<options>]{<image>}
  \captionof{figure}{<caption>}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to make the point of some things here, also because I don't agree with the approach suggested in the answer posted by @Mattia. There is a bit of confusion here about some heavy matters: positioning figures, floats, captions.

First, the `center` environment is mainly meant to be used to center [*text* paragraphs](http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/environ.htm#center) rather than images, `figure` should be used here instead.

Further, to nest `center` and `figure` is definitely overmuch. Better to use `\centering` command, inside a `figure` environment. Nesting these two environments may result in excessive vertical margins around the figure and - I think - makes the code overabundant.

Ah, `figure` environment makes the image a *float*, hence the use of something like `[h]` or `[!h]` (or `float` package, as suggested by Werner) to force positioning in case of necessity. But, on the other hand, `figure` also [allows the use of a dedicated command `\caption{ }`](http://www.andy-roberts.net/writing/latex/floats_figures_captions) inside.

Finally (this was not requested, I only write this to complete my code below), if you need to label your figure, then the `\caption{ }` command must come before `\label{ }`.

The resulting code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

Text paragraph.

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=13.7cm, height=8.2cm]{pictures/c25k.png}
\caption{Here the caption.}
%\label{img1}
\end{figure}

Text paragraph %\ref{img1} and some other text

\end{document}
```