# Why can I not use a \caption inside the center environment?

Tags: captions

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=.2]{er.png}
\caption{Activity diagram of Privacy Protection in Smartphone’s by using Mobile Cloud Framework}
\end{center}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Also, change `Smartphone’s` by `Smartphone's`. If after this change and the one pointed by koleygr you still get errors, then please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Use  `\usepackage{caption}`  in the  preamble and `\captionof{figure}{Activity...}`, if you really need the `center` environment instead of the `figure` environment

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik in the default utf-8 setup `Smartphone’s` and `Smartphone's` come to the same thing (but here it should be `Smartphones`  anyway)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I had read everything but the actual sentence :P

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I did just a quick search, but I couldn’t find an existing duplicate of this question.  This looks pretty surprising, but if it is really the case that this question has never been asked before, you should convert your comment (which gives the correct solution) into an answer.

Comment: @GuM ... too late. Another one 'stole' my comment ;-) Well, my fate here....

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Yes, already seen (and upvoted! ;-)

Comment: My comment seems funny after the title edit :P... Deleting... Also possible related/dupplicate of this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280557/latex-how-to-add-caption-in-begincenter but not flagging since too many things happened before the OP say a word...(if ever)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - My apologies -- I somehow completely missed your comment. I'll go ahead and upvote some of your recent answers (which I nearly alsways do anyway!).

Comment: @Mico: No worries... I will miss your posts

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - All I can offer at this point are my abject apologies. I'll try hard(er) to avoid any repeat of this lapse.

Comment: @Mico: I don't understand what you mean.... there's nothing to apologize by you.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - I was reacting to your ` I will miss your posts` comment, which sounds to me like you might be considering quitting this site entirely in disgust over how you get treated a times. Did I misinterpret you?

Comment: @Mico: I think we're helping too much sometimes and getting not the appreciation we deserve. Who helped us 20 etc. or more years ago? I will reduce my time for TeX.SE, most likely -- actually I have already reduced it

Answer (score 5):

`\caption` must occur inside a "floating" environment such as `figure` or `table`. A `center` environment is *not* a floating environment. I think what you want to employ is a `\captionof{figure}{...}` statement. Load the `caption` package to get access to `\captionof`.

Oh, and I'm pretty sure it should be `Smartphones`, not `Smartphone’s`...

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage{caption} % for \captionof macro
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=.2]{er.png}
\captionof{figure}{Activity diagram of Privacy Protection in 
   Smartphones by using Mobile Cloud Framework}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```